# Error Running Ruby Debug IDE with Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-debug-ide

I am having a problem running a Rails 4 app with Ruby Debug IDE using Visual Studio Code. This is the error I get.

```
/home/ziyan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2158:in `method_missing'
: undefined method `this' for #<Gem::Specification:0x1271b08 debase-0.2.1> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/ziyan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1057:in `find_active_stub_by_path'
    from /home/ziyan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:64:in `require'
    from /home/ziyan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@tbv_website/gems/debase-0.2.1/lib/debase.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ziyan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `require'
    from /home/ziyan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `rescue in require'
    from /home/ziyan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
    from /home/ziyan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@tbv_website/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ziyan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@tbv_website/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0/bin/rdebug-ide:8:in `require_relative'
    from /home/ziyan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@tbv_website/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0/bin/rdebug-ide:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ziyan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@tbv_website/bin/rdebug-ide:23:in `load'
    from /home/ziyan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@tbv_website/bin/rdebug-ide:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/ziyan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@tbv_website/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/ziyan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@tbv_website/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

#### Extra details

- Ruby 2.3.0
- Ruby Debug IDE 0.6
- IDE: Visual Studio Code + [vscode-ruby](https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby)

#### Different variations tried

- Tried updating to Ruby 2.3.3
- Tried downgrading ruby-debug-ide to 0.5
- Tried upgrading ruby-debug-ide to 0.6.1.beta4

With no success

#### Extra

I started a new Rails 5 + Ruby 2.4.0 project and debugging works fine with it. It uses the same ruby-debug-ide version. So the version of ruby-debug-ide should be working.

Comment: I would guess that your `Gemfile` includes a `this` method call.perhaps it should be a comment and the `#` in front of the word is missing? Btw: The error also tells that you use Ruby `2.3` not `2.4` - you might want to check that.

Comment: I would add that I used the same extension to debug Ruby 2.1.x and Ruby 2.2.x Rails applications and it worked fine. It stopped working for me passing to Ruby 2.3.x (failed with .0, .1 and .3).

Comment: Thanks @MarcoSanfilippo, I couldn't update to 2.4 because some lib broke. I will try with 2.2.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just solved the issue by updating rubygems to version 2.6.11 (I think it's the latest version available as of today).

```
$ gem update --system
```

Now debugging in VSCode works again.

My current config.

- CentOS 7
- RVM, latest stable
- VSCode, latest stable with Ruby extension 0.10.4
- Rails 4 - Ruby 2.3.3 (currently working on a Solidus-based e-commerce)
- Debase 0.2.1, Ruby-Debug-IDE 0.6.1b4

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Great let me give it a try!